# Why does putting a table inside a flex container with align-items: center mess up scrolling on overflow?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I am trying to create a responsive table by letting the table be scrollable in the x-axis.  The code below works as I want.  However, if I add `align-items: center;` to the body's styling, the table won't scroll anymore.  Why is that, and is there a good way to work around this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

div {
  overflow-x:auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Table</h2>
<p>This paragraph should be centred, as well as the table below.</p>

<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a js-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p72g5ast/

Comment: What do you need `align-items: center;` for?

Comment: To center other elements in the flex container that don't take up the entire width.

Comment: I know there are other ways to center those child elements.  I'm less interested in how to specifically do that and more interested in an explanation why doing the above doesn't work, and if possible, an easy workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `align-items: center`, you are removing the default `align-items: stretch`. In a column nowrap flexbox, `align-items: stretch` is essentially the same as `width:100%` on each of the flex items.

To get the behavior you want on on the table after adding `align-items: center` you can add `align-self: stretch` or `width:100%` on the tablewrapper.

The reason scrolls stop happening is that without the `stretch`/`width:100%`, the `body` flexbox asked tablewrapper what width it wanted to be (its `max-content`), and the tabblewrapper made itself the exact width of its only child (the table) because that's roughly how `max-content` calculation works when you have one child. So because the tablewrapper and table had exactly the same width, the tablewrapper never had overflow so never showed a scrollbar.

Now that I added width:100% to the tablewrapper, the flexbox always makes tablewrapper the same width as the flexbox. So when the table is wider than the flexbox/body/screen/tablewrapper, there is overflow and a scrollbar appears.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Responsive Table</h2>
<p>If you have a table that is too wide, you can add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the table, and it will display a horizontal scroll bar when needed.</p>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect. Try to remove the div element and see what happens to the table.</p>

<div style="overflow-x:auto; width:100%;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give div fixed width for table overflow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      align-items:center;
    }
    table {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .tablewrapper {
      width:130px;
      overflow-x:auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Responsive Table</h2>
  <p>This paragraph should be centred, as well as the table below.</p>
  <div class="tablewrapper">
    <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The table doesn't scroll horizontally on overflow

Comment: I've updated answer. If you want overflow then surely need to wrap with div but also give fixed width to div.

Comment: Oh, I see what's happening.  Thanks!  Do you know why when I add ```align-items: center```, I need to add a fixed width?  Whereas without it, it will automatically create a scrollbar if its parent become too small.